# Styles are not applied to external components from a different package in NextJs SSR

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I am using an external react component that is imported into my nextjs app code, this is how the component looks like

```
<AppBar className={clsx(classes.header)}>
</AppBar>



export const header = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    header: {
        [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            padding: `0 ${theme.spacing(4)}px`,
        },
    },
})
```

However the actual CSS is not applied when the page is server side rendered.

This all works perfectly with client side rendering aka hydration that is done after the page is loaded onto the client's browser but it is only in the server side rendering with Nextjs, it is failing

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening - your AppBar component gets passed a className prop, but it doesn't know what to do with it. HTML elements do take a className prop for styling, but you have to code your custom components to do something with the className (such as passing the className to the outermost HTML element in your component).

For example, a className prop would have no effect on the following component:

```
export default function AppBar() {
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But it would have an effect on the following component because it would apply the class to the top level div:

```
export default function AppBar({className}) {
    return (
        <div className={className}>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Your AppBar component needs to properly handle the className prop.

EDIT: Upon further investigation, it seems that the Material UI AppBar component is a styled component. I have found the following GitHub gist which seems to be achieving what you want: https://gist.github.com/Danilo-Araujo-Silva/2ce11fd0540dcc7eb3ad3e67fd75d02a

Comment: Thanks for writing this, this is working fine on the client side rendering, the problem is with server side rendering only. I dont think this answer applies to the problem I am facing

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using `makeStyles`, which is a very old and outdated utility from the deprecated `@mui/styles` package. Are you also using a more recent version of React (18+) and/or Next.js (13+)? If so, you might be encountering fundamental incompatibilities between these packages. `@mui/styles` will not be updated to work with future React versions beyond 17.

Comment: What are the possible solutions to this ? Because I cant control external packages too much and ask them to change since it is working fine on client side rendering.